# Marketplace Publish Failure - 1100.7.3 Duplicate Offer?

Tags: powerbi

We are currently creating Power BI Custom Visuals for our clients to use it internally. As part of the solution, we wanted to export the Custom Power BI Visuals as PPT file. Since this can be accomplished only if we get the PBI visual published and certified, we are currently in the process of publishing the visuals to Marketplace and get it certified. Since we are creating these visuals for multiple clients, even though the base visual is same but there are some differences like background image, colour scheme etc. So we have submitted 2 different products to marketplace with separate package. We just received an failure message stating that “Your offer is a duplicate of an offer you have previously submitted”. Is there any option to go around this issue. Please let us know.
Also for Custom Visuals that are not meant for Public usage, is there any other option to save it as PPT. Please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You must combine both visuals into one and allow the customizations to be made using their properties. For example having a property to specify the background image, properties for setting elements color, etc.

I guess `PPT` is PowerPoint (.pptx). No, currently uncertified custom visuals are not supported, as stated in the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-powerpoint#considerations-and-troubleshooting):

> - Power BI visuals that have been certified are supported. For more information on certified custom visuals, including how to get a custom visual certified, see Get a custom visual certified. **Custom visuals that haven't been certified aren't supported.** They're exported as a blank image into PowerPoint with an error message that states the visual isn't supported.

The only option to do that is to use 3rd party tools. You may take a look at [Power BI Robots](https://www.powerbitiles.com/?app=PBIRobots) which **may** (I don't use them, so I can't confirm for sure) work with uncertified visuals.